# Those who or who?

Tags: phrase-choice, relative-pronouns

1. > Thank you, Lord, for the teachers **those who** care for me.
2. > Thank you, Lord, for the teachers **who** care for me.

Which of these two would be more correct?

Comment: The second is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2, *"Thank you, Lord, for the teachers who care for me"*, is correct.

In order for Option 1 to be correct, there would have to be additional punctuation to break up the sentence appropriately.

Comment: Please do not use code markdown on this site. It almost never means anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, "...the teachers -- those who care for me", the those-who phrase is in apposition to "the teachers" and is supplemental.

In the second version, "...the teachers who care for me",  the who-clause is subordinate.

The first version is somewhat unusual; it is a stylized utterance, in a non-conversational, somewhat formal register, not inappropriate for a prayer said by a congregation.  The second is normal.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how #1 could be correct at all. You could say, "Thank you for those who care for me". I suppose if you added commas "those" could refer back, like "thank you for teachers, those who care for me", though even that seems pretty awkward to me.

Comment: I think my explanation already addresses the concerns you raise, Jay.

Comment: Consider another example of an appositional supplemental phrase (again in the context of a prayer, to address the "seems-pretty-awkward" challenge you raise--it is not everyday speech): *Let us pray for the homeless--those who have no roof over their heads.*

Comment: Also, with respect to punctuation ("I suppose if you added commas..."): punctuation does not *impart* grammaticality, rather it *reflects* grammaticality.

Comment: Impart vs reflect: Hmm, maybe that depends on your definition of "grammar", but I think by the conventional definition, if I took an otherwise correct paragraph and changed all the periods to quotation marks and all the commas to question marks, I think people would say that the paragraph was now "grammatically incorrect".

Comment: People might say that, but they'd be wrong.  If your language was grammatical to begin with, your paragraph would simply be punctuated incorrectly.